# How do you copy a meeting in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office

How do I copy a meeting in Outlook on Mac?   On PC you just use Copy/Paste.  On Mac, all the Edit commands are disabled when you select a meeting in the Outlook calendar.

I spend time setting up a meeting with participants, location, attachments, categories, etc etc etc and I want to create a copy of it or a variation of it without starting from scratch.  Is this just one of those "on our to do list" features of Outlook on Mac?

Comment: Please consider accepting [DerekC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370927/290197)'s answer as it is (by far) the least complicated way to simply copy an appointment

Comment: @stevec you're right.   Option-Drag.  I wasn't aware I had accepted a more complicated answer ... I've been using DerekC's suggestion since he made it.  Changed, and thank you.

Comment: I removed "2016" from the question.   If you're still using Outlook 2016 in 2022, the formerly accepted answer is still there, but I'm accepting a new answer that I believe is more relevant today, for "Outlook for Mac" with an Office 365 subscription.

Comment: Shift + Cmd + C. Then, choose the destination calendar. I think this might only be possible if the Event doesn't have any attendees.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A workaround option is to do this through Office 365 Outlook web app (https://outlook.office365.com) since none of the Mac Outlook options worked for me. When you've logged in, right click the event you want to duplicate, and you should be able to click on the option to duplicate it.

[image: Duplicate Event Option on O365 Outlook]

Comment: At this time, December 2 2020, this is the best answer for those who have "New Outlook".  Hoping this situation is temporary, I'll wait until a suitable feature is re-introduced into New Outlook before changing the best answer checked here.

Comment: Well another two years have passed and you still can't do this in Mac Outlook, and I think Outlook 2016 is now of far less interest.   I have accepted this answer, which is appropriate for the current version of Outlook on Mac with an Office 365 subscription.  Without 365 I believe there is no way to do it. :(

Comment: The question is about working in Outlook for Mac. I don't see how this is the accepted solution

Comment: @DerekC If you apply a reasonable interpretation of the question, ie, "How can a user of Outlook for Mac accomplish task X" this answer is the best and only one.  If you apply an unreasonably precise interpretation of the question, I'll counter with a suitable answer: Accepted means OP accepts it.  It means no more and no less than that.  You can have accepted answers with downvotes. (I'm not encouraging you to do that!)

Comment: @DerekC if it makes you feel any better, the check mark has a tinge of bitterness and irony.  Look carefully.  :)

Answer (score 10):

I have Outlook for Mac [16.29]

I am able to `[alt/option]+[click]+drag` an appointment.
The result is a copy of the appointment in a new location / timeslot...! Yay!

*I must admit, I never tried this before - it could work in older versions.*

[image]

Comment: Woo hoo!  This works.  I also have 16.29, and also don't know if it worked in earlier versions but I'm fairly certain I tried this about a year ago when I asked this question.   Awesome answer, thank you.

Comment: Does not work in 2020 with any other buttons, if it shows the dotted lines it moves the meeting instead of copying it

Comment: @blub same issue here. Seems Microsoft wants to make Mac users' experience worse and worse.

Comment: @blub it worked for me (Outlook version 16.41)

Comment: Note, this solution "Option-Drag" does not work in "New Outlook".  If you have MacOs 10.14+, Outlook 16.42+, and choose the available (and default) "New Outlook" mode, Option-Drag will move rather than copy the event.  I've filed this as a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: Still works for me on Outlook 16.43

Comment: I can't see a way to make this work when I want to copy the event to a different week (it doesn't drag and drop onto the month view.).  I wish Microsoft would support the "duplicate" function they have in the web client.  My company requires me to use the desktop client.

Comment: @JoshuaRichardson in calendar view, click-drag the month (left sidebar) to select multiple weeks. Then you can use this method.

Comment: Does not work on my Outlook 16.55 on Mac. Wondering if there's a config setting related to this. Sigh.

Comment: @Thogek this method *still* does not work in "New Outlook" mode, and now two over years after New Outlook was released I think it is safe to say this method is defunct.

Comment: I am probably going to unaccept this answer since it has been more than two years since it stopped working for what was THEN "new outlook".   I will write an answer that refers to this one, in case Microsoft ever fixes it and also refers to one of the other  less elegant answers.

Comment: My answer is valid for the OP's question. I don't use the New Look in Outlook (due to lack of multi-account features) and the solution as proposed still works for me.

Comment: This was my Accepted answer for about 3 years.  I have changed the question (in 2022) so it is no longer specific to Outlook 2016, and accepted a new answer more relevant today.  But this answer will live on for those still using 2016.

Comment: My solution [Option+Drag] still works if you are *not* in the “New Outlook” Theme/View and you have no other attendees. I use it every week to copy appointments between days. 

Unfortunately, Microsoft has not enabled a way to copy appointments with other attendees yet… :/

Answer (score 8):

This is also a workaround but maybe a *little* quicker.

- In calendar view, select original meeting
- Click on the **Reply All** button in the ribbon -> this creates an email to all attendees
- Save this
- In **drafts** folder select the email you just created
- Click on the **meeting** button in the ribbon -> this creates a new meeting request for all attendees of the original with the same basic content (notable exception being the location)
- Edit the meeting request as desired, perhaps replacing 'RE:' in the subject line with 'Follow-up', adding a time, location or online meeting details and any new text.
- Send it once ready

Comment: I'm not sure that's easier than Option-Drag but this might come in handy sometimes.  Tx.

Comment: This (unfortunately) is actually the only working solution

Comment: This worked for me (version 16.52), but caution, I forgot to update the date before sending the invite initially, and every time I opened the meeting and resent it with the correct date, it would just revert to the old date.  So make sure you get the date correct the first time.

Comment: Ugh! This works. What a pain. If you can't find the **meeting** button (step 4), don't open the email. Just select it.

Comment: Didnt work for me, there's no **meeting** button :(

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to get this to work in any shipping version of Office 2016 and the pre-release / Insider builds of Office 2019 for Mac.

I've had good luck using the built in app support to ask if I'm missing some feature and they suggested user voice feedback - and I've seen some good movement and communication from the management of Office for Mac on the user voice site showing what features they are working on, which ship, which are known but not actively being worked.

Here's the one (of several) asking for this feature and it has a lot of votes, but more votes could help it rise to the top.

- https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/13874721-add-copy-paste-function-to-calendar-meetings

tl;dr -  A lot of people can't figure out how this works and want the feature added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   Now that I've been a Mac user for about 6 months I feel compelled to add here that Outlook for Mac is far and away the worst part of the Mac experience.   For the most part, there are things I miss about Windows and things I like about Mac, it's not really that exciting but Outlook for Mac just blows it all away, it's such a terrible experience and ruins any benefits the Mac might bring to my life.

Comment: Imagine how bad outlooo for Mac was in the past for us to like this version. @jay613 thanks for sharing your experience. I don’t doubt it’s frustrating

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I came here looking for an answer, so this may help someone...

Option + Click/Drag doesn't seem to work for newer Outlooks/MacOS's, however I did find that the following works well enough:

1. **Control** + **Click** the Event
2. Expand the **Move** menu item
3. Select **Copy to Folder...**
4. Select your own current **Calendar** (usually default)
5. Click **OK**
6. **Drag** the copied Event to wherever you wanted to copy it to

OK, sounds long winded, but it's relatively easy and since I thought there wasn't even a way of doing it 10 minutes ago, I'm pretty happy with it!

Comment: Thanks @Daz Butterworth, I came on to say I found the same solution and it just works (not exactly intuitive - but works!)

Comment: Nice find.  Can confirm it works in v16.70

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit kludgy, I admit.
You need to be linked to a second calendar account for this to work.

Note: This only works when you display calendar events as a list. (View->List, or Ctrl-Command-0)

1. **Copy** your calendar event from the original calendar to the second calendar (using <kbd>Option</kbd>+Click)
2. **Move** the event back from the second calendar to the original calendar. You now have to identical events in your calendar.
3. If you need multiple copies, copy the event from the second calendar instead of moving it.

Works on my Mac with Outlook 16.27. YMMV

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what you are referring to here.   Option-Click usually reveals hidden menu entries.  Which menu should I Option-Click on?   I tried some obvious ones (The calendar entry's right-button menu, and all Outlook's application menus) but nothing reveals "copy to a different calendar".   I do have another calendar to try this if I can understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: @jay613 I forgot to mention that this only works in list view. My apologies! I updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, this works.  It is deeply disturbing  :)   But it works, and it's actually quite easy.    May I suggest a couple of edits to your answer: 1) Instead of Option-Click say Option-Drag (I had to figure that out).    2) My primary calendar is employer's Exchange, secondary is personal Outlook Online.  The nice thing there is it retains ALL the Outlook-specific attributes.  You should recommend using Outlook Online (free) as the vehicle for this. Thanks!  (Edit: Actually I can edit your answer, do you mind?)

Answer (score -3):

This is a ridiculous answer but is the simplest. Use Fantastical. You just right click and choose duplicate event. Why the option+drag feature is not working in Outlook is a disgrace so as usual you have to use a 3rd party app to get the functionality that Windows users don't even have to worry about.

Comment: Outlook is a 3rd party application as well…

Comment: Most people, and I think it is probably safe to say all people (though I have no proof) who use Outlook on Mac are required to use Outlook by their employer, school, etc.  Sometimes I appreciate this kind of "avoid the problem" answer but here it is useless.